# Android share image on twitter using intent

Tags: android-intent, twitter

I have the same code working for Instagram, but Twitter is causing problems - Twitter shows white screen and stops/crashes back to my own app.

```
if (sharedFileImageJpeg != null) {
  try {
    contentUri_internal_fileprovider = FileProvider.getUriForFile(thisActivityContext, "com.example.app.fileprovider", sharedFileImageJpeg);              
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    String debug_s = e.toString();
  }
}

package_name = "com.twitter.android";
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setPackage(package_name);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri_internal_fileprovider);
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
startActivity(shareIntent);
```